# Why can't the Tor Browser run Adobe Flash Player?

Tags: anonymity, tor-browser-bundle, plugin, flash

I've tried to play some games that need the Adobe Flash Player but they don't load. I'd like to stay anonymous but also play those games.

Why can't the Tor Browser run Adobe Flash Player?